# No such external account and my Stripe Payout not working using php?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

**I am transferring fund from stripe account to connect account using payout api**
my code is:

```
 $payout = \Stripe\Payout::create([
                    'amount' => 500,
                    'currency' => 'aud',
                    'description' => 'first payout payment transfer on stripe',
                    'destination' => 'bank_id',
                    'method' => 'instant',
                    'source_type' => 'bank_account',
                    'statement_descriptor' => 'first payout payment transfer on stripe ',
        ]);
```

after hit this api show error:

> Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException: No such external account:
>   ba_1G497bAoBoRegJgCC1jj2UE2 in file
>   /var/www/html/ultimateFitness/app/Stripe/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php
>   on line 38

Also i am follow stripe documentation:
[https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/creat](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/create)e

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the call on behalf of the connected account — right now it gives an error because it's looking for the bank account on *your* Stripe account, not the connected one.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication

```
$payout = \Stripe\Payout::create([
    'amount' => 500,
    'currency' => 'aud',
    'description' => 'first payout payment transfer on stripe',
    'destination' => $bank_id,
    'method' => 'instant',
    'source_type' => 'bank_account',
    'statement_descriptor' => 'first payout payment transfer on stripe ',
],
["stripe_account" => "{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}"]); // value like "acct_xxx"
```